# Writing the number of sentence symbols in a wff by recursion

Tags: logic

How do I write the number of sentence symbols in a wff by recursion?

Attempt: Let $A=A_1\Box A_2\Box\ldots\Box A_n$ be a wff where $A_i$'s are sentence symbols with connectives $\Box$. How do I define $n = h(A):A\to f(h(A)) = f(n)$ recursively as a function of $A$?

Comment: I have edited the question to replace special characters with Mathjax symbols. Please check that I didn't change the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly, the number $a(\alpha)$ of atomic symbols can be defined as follows:

$\begin{cases} a(\alpha)=1 \text{ for } \alpha \text{ atomic} \\ 
a(\neg\alpha)=a(\alpha) \\
a(\alpha \to \beta)=a(\alpha)+a(\beta) \\
a(\forall x \alpha)=a(\alpha)
\end{cases}$

where $a:FORM \to \mathbb{N}$

**Examples**

- $a(S(c)\to B)=a(S(c))+a(B)=2$
- $a(\forall x (\neg S(x)))=a((\neg S(x)))=a(S(x))=1$
- $a(c = f(d))=1$

This is probably the best we can do, since you did not specify your language.